# How to find a sum of combination given specific group?

Tags: python

I am seeking for help to find all the possible sum of combinations < certain amount. Given the following table:

```
 [-inf,546) [546, 551)  [551, 556)
0   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
100 $29.37  $26.90  $25.81
200 $58.74  $53.80  $51.62
300 $88.12  $80.70  $77.43
400 $117.49 $107.61 $103.24
500 $146.86 $134.51 $129.04
```

Example of combination:

1. $0.00 + $0.00 + $0.00 {0: [-inf,546), 0: [546, 551), 0:[551, 556)}
2. $0.00 + $0.00 + $25.81 {0: [-inf,546), 0: [546, 551), 100:[551, 556)}
3. $0.00 + $0.00 + $51.62 {0: [-inf,546), 0: [546, 551), 200:[551, 556)}
4. $29.37 + $0.00 + $0.00 {100: [-inf,546), 0: [546, 551), 200:[551, 556)}

etc.

I am not sure what kind of keyword I can search for this kind of problem. Really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: I think I have found my answer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/. This can give me all combination, but I only need 1, 4, 7 etc of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from `itertools`.

In this example, the condition will be that the sum has to be smaller than `20`:

```
from itertools import combinations

nums = [12, 21, 1, 3, 6, 7, 54, 2, 13, 32]

combs = []

for comb in combinations(nums, 3):
    c = sum(comb)
    if c not in combs and c < 20:
        combs.append(c)
        print(c)

print(combs)
```

Output:

```
16
19
15
17
10
11
6
14
9
12
18
[16, 19, 15, 17, 10, 11, 6, 14, 9, 12, 18]
```

Comment: I think I have found my answer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/. This can give me all combination, but I only need 1, 4, 7 etc of the result.